# Problems attempting to read web.config from a Windows application

Tags: web-config, appsettings, webconfigurationmanager

I'm writing a WPF application to help non-XML-savvy customers set up configuration files on a web server.  web.config is one of these files.  I have custom sections defined, but I've commented them out until I get the basics working.

In web.config, I have this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="buffer" value="65536"/>
    <add key="updateInterval" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
```

Here's a snippet of how I'm reading web.config (I have already confirmed that web.config exists inside AppPath):

```
var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(AppPath, true);
var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
```

However, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["buffer"] returns null.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duhhhh.  It's Monday morning.  :-)

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
config.AppSettings["buffer"];
```

works.